# How to configure HWIOAuthBundle and FOSUserBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I am configuring Fosuserbundle and HWIOAuth Bundle to Login from Facebook and Google.
issue i am facing is:
When i try to login a user through google account , when he is not already logged in , as i enter credentials of Google and press login it shows me error

```
No route found for GET/
```

Or some times

```
No route found for GET/ ( from   wwww.mysite.com/app_dev.php/en/home/ )
```

it does store information of user (e.g Email , user name etc) in databases , when i go to home page i find my self logged in.

When i try to log in a user who is already logged in with hi google account , it works perfectly.

I am stuck with this...  Step by step followed [**This**](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697) documentation. Everything is working perfectly except this.

You help would be appreciated.

config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
    #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
    #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
    #and also, the connecting part (get the token and the user_id)
    connect:
        account_connector: my_user_provider
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: main
    fosub:
#        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            # these properties will be used/redefined later in the custom FOSUBUserProvider service.
            facebook: facebook_id
            google: google_id
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            client_secret:       "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            scope:               ""
        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            client_secret:       "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

--------------------security.yml------------

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                provider: fos_userbundle

#                always_use_default_target_path: true
#                default_target_path:            /%locale%/home

            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:             "/login/check-google"
                login_path:        /login
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                                     #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
                                     #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
                       service: my_user_provider
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /%locale%/home
            anonymous: ~
```

-----------------routing.yml------------

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

#HWIOAuthBundle routes
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /login

facebook_login:
    pattern: /login/check-facebook

google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google
```

Comment: Is it doing the login and then forwarding to that error?

Comment: yeah exactly, doing login and then error... @Qoop

Comment: Then it looks like it's trying to find a route with the path `/` and there isn't one. I believe the default target path is `/`.

Comment: what it should be ? @Qoop

Comment: Whatever path or route you want the logged in users to be redirected to. You can either set a path (`/something/somethingelse`) or a route name (`acme_blog_comment`). Either that or create a route that has the path `/`.

Comment: @Qoop basically , when user is already logged in from google or facebook it redirects it successfully, but in case , he has to log in on the spot using website interface google it shows that error.

Comment: So if a user goes to a page and then logs in with oauth it routes correctly and if using the form login it takes them to `/`?

Comment: kindly have a look on the link i mentioned , which i am following.
I am not using form to save information of user,  i did overriding of two functions.
which automatically picks up the data from response, and takes to the success page.
but often... not all the time.

Comment: I have read the link, using that link doesn't specifically mean that aren't going to be using a form_login, it just says that you are going to be using oAuth as a login provider. When a user goes to a path that isn't the login and is logged in where does it go? When a user goes to the login path and is logged in what happens?

Comment: steps:
case 1: I am not logged in with my google account right now.
i goto my website , hit connect with google, it takes me to login page of google , i log in there as i hit login , i expect it to take me to my success page or confirmation page.
it takes me to www.mysite.com/app_dev.php/
and shows me error...